# Hosting multiple asp.net core on ubuntu server with NGINX

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx, hosting, web-hosting

I'm getting crazy trying to host my 3 asp.net core services on a ubuntu server 22.04.

I managed to host correctly 2 static index.html pages following this tutorial: https://webdock.io/en/docs/how-guides/shared-hosting-multiple-websites/how-configure-nginx-to-serve-multiple-websites-single-vps

this is the response when I Curl http://{my ip address}/web2.webdock.io/ :

```
<html>
<title>web2.webdock.io</title>
<h1>Welcome to the web2.webdock.io with Nginx webserver.</h1>
</html>
```

using this configuration

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/web2.webdock.io;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name web2.webdock.io;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

}
```

When I try to do the same with my asp.net core api it doesn't work the same way. Here is my config file in the sites-enabled folder:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name compliance;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

curl http://{my IP address}/compliance/ :

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm totally lost. Just spent 6hours at work trying to get this working without any success.
And of course my api works perfectly in localhost:5001

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is your app running? As it is 404 not found, server was unable to locate the requested resource, such as filename or any specific URL.

Comment: Yes the apps are running at localhost:5000, localhost:5001, localhost:5002

Comment: would you please check nginx log?